# Why is my TPS62162DSGT regulator burning?

Tags: voltage-regulator, heat, switching-regulator

I need a 12V and 3.3V power supply for a circuit, so I designed a regulator onto a board to turn the 12V to 3.3V. I used the TI [TPS62162DSGT](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/TPS62162DSGT/296-29897-1-ND/2782627) to do this, and my schematic looks like:

[image: Schematic of board]

I used the inductor and capacitor [BKPB001608DZ2R2MA2](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/chilisin-electronics/BKPB001608DZ2R2MA2/2184-BKPB001608DZ2R2MA2CT-ND/10509140) and [GRM188R60J226MEA0D](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/murata-electronics/GRM188R60J226MEA0D/490-7611-1-ND/4280544) respectively along with this small test board:

[image: Board layout]

I soldered up the board using low temp solder paste and a hot plate, which is less than ideal. But I expected it'd be fine for a test. Checking the components, they seem like they are soldered correctly and in place:

[image: Physical board]

I checked all of the connections and found no shorts, and the capacitance is correct. Unfortunately my multi-meter won't measure inductance. I plugged it in, and it worked fine, although the voltage I measured was only 3.26V. I unplugged it and plugged it back in 2 more times, there was a pop, the device began heating, and the housing briefly caught fire. This has happened twice now, so I suspect a design failure on my part, but I've checked the datasheet and TI's "WEBENCH" numerous times, and can't pin it down. Maybe the ground or voltage side is making contact first, but it wasn't grounding through anything so far as I can tell (off the table). I feel like an idiot, but does anyone know what's happening, I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The datasheet says the PG pin doesn't need to be connected. You can either pull it high on the output, leave it open, or connect it to ground. I left it open because when I first made it it wasn't on the eagle cad library. I added it later.

Comment: Do you have any load connected to the 3.3V side?  If so, what and how is it connected?

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis  I hadn't tested it with a load yet.

Comment: What is supplying your 12V power to the input?  Since it sounds the failure occurs when hot plugging into the 12V, I suspect a transient overvoltage on the input due to the input supply overshooting or line inductance and bouncing contacts.  Can you put a scope on the input voltage?  You could solder a TVS device right across the input terminals to absorb any transient overvoltage.

Comment: @JohnD I was just using a supply lying around. It's a GEM18112-P1j https://www.newegg.com/p/1HU-022R-001G0 . I guess I thought the capacitor would protect me. Maybe not though.

Comment: @JohnD I can't easily scope the circuit until next week when I'll get new components, but then I will test with TVS and scope it.

Comment: @SillyInventor The input cap should help, but it's a ceramic 10uF which may not have much capacitance left with 12V DC bias on it.  Can't tell without knowing the part number though.  Also hard to say what the response of your 12V adapter is, though it does have OVP at 140% of rated voltage so it theoretically shouldn't reach 17V.

Comment: Are you sure you got the fix output voltage version of the chip ?

Comment: @Mike The OP says it regulated initially, and even if it wasn't the fixed version it shouldn't blow up with 12V applied to the input.

Comment: Possible scenario: The supply is not grounded. There's likely some high voltage on the DC output relative to ground when it is not connected to anything. This is due to internal capacitance to mains inside the supply. When you plug the supply in, sometimes the high voltage pops the regulator on your board. You may avoid this by either using a grounded supply, having more input capacitance, using a connector which connects ground first, then connecting 12V, incorporating a zener across the input, switching off the supply at mains rather than plugging/unplugging.

Comment: Does the TPS62162DSGT need a minimum load to keep from blowing up?

Comment: @Mike I bought it from that link to digikey. Admittedly, I didn't check the text on the chip (it's tiny) but I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @elchambro I will test a TVS next week when I get one, and let you know.

Comment: @evildemonic the datasheet only references 'very light loads' and says that it has a special power saver mode for those. Some of the graphs go down to 0, but it's hard to know if that's really 0 or <1mA. I'll try starting it with a load, and then try without a load to pin it down next week (maybe Wednesday?)

Comment: The part does not require a minimum load to regulate or keep from blowing up.

Comment: @JohnD and elchambro I tried out a TVS diode, and it solved my problem. John D, if you make it an answer I can select it to be so (and hence help others).

Comment: @SillyInventor Done, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it sounds the failure occurs when hot plugging into the 12V, I suspect a transient overvoltage on the input due to the input supply overshooting or line inductance and bouncing contacts. You could solder a TVS device right across the input terminals to absorb any transient overvoltage.